# How to count a global variable?

Tags: extjs

**LoginController:**

`var AppConstants = Ext.widget("AppConstants"); AppConstants.setGLOBAL_id_user(id_user);`

**App:**

`var AppConstants = Ext.widget("AppConstants"); console.log(AppConstants.getGLOBAL_id_user());`

**Console:** `(an empty string)`

How to count a global variable?

Comment: Please provide more information about count. What exactly you want?

Comment: I want the value of the variable that was written to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

`Ext.widget()` creates a new instance of a certain class every time you call it.

What you want is something that does not create new instances.

For minimal change to your code, you could do `Ext.AppConstants = Ext.widget('Appconstants')` in `Application.init()` and then access `Ext.AppConstants` wherever you use `Ext.widget('Appconstants')` right now.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you could use [`singleton`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-singleton) class in **ExtJS**. Using a singleton class you can access all the variable in throughout application whenever you required.

In this [`FIDDLE`](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gld), I have created a demo using `singleton` class. Hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        //{singleton: true,} When set to true, the class will be instantiated as singleton.
        Ext.define('AppConstants', {
            alternateClassName: 'AppConstants',
            singleton: true,

            config: {
                GLOBAL_id_user: 'Demo_123'
            },

            constructor: function (config) {
                this.initConfig(config);
            }
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',

            title: 'Demo',

            bodyPadding: 15,

            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Set value',
                margin: '0 15',
                handler: function () {

                    //we set value using setter of singleton.
                    Ext.Msg.prompt('Set GLOBAL_id_user', 'Please enter GLOBAL_id_user value', function (btn, text) {
                        if (btn == 'ok') {
                            AppConstants.setGLOBAL_id_user(text);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Get value',
                handler: function () {
                    //we get value using getter of singleton.
                    Ext.Msg.alert('GLOBAL_id_user value is ', AppConstants.getGLOBAL_id_user());
                }
            }],

            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The code you sent works, however, the value of the variable is not passed from the controller to the global variable. That is, on the authorization page where the controller operates the value is written, I see it through the console, but the application page is not displayed.

Comment: **Controller:** `AppConstants.setGLOBAL_id_user(id_user);
console.log('AppConstants.getGLOBAL_id_user');`

Comment: First no need this line `AppConstants.GLOBAL_id_user = id_user;` in your function `onSubmit`. and have you define singleton class ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a global singleton

```
Ext.define("MyApp.globals", {
   singleton: true,
   id_user: 0
});
```

Then access it using `MyApp.globals.id_user`

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-singleton